# Restrict acess Basic Auth to all but one file+query string

Tags: apache, .htaccess, query-string, basic-authentication

I need to prevent access to all files in a dir but one specific file, with a specific query string. I've been trying this so far, but I REQUEST_URI doesn't have the QUERY STRING

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI ^index.php?myquery$ noauth=1
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /home/user/.htpasswd
AuthName "Pass"

Order Deny,Allow
Satisfy any
Deny from all
Require valid-user
Allow from env=noauth
```

Again, the user should only be able to access index.php?myquery. Not index.php or anything.php?myquery

Answer (score 1):

SetEnvIf cannot access the query string in Apache 2.2.  In 2.4, you could access the query string in a 2nd SetEnvIf or just use <if>

Here's a simple example in mod_rewrite though that works in 2.2 vhost context:

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} =/index.php
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} =myquery
RewriteRule .* - [E=noauth:1]
```

Note: doesn't work in htaccess/per-dir context

Comment: The problem here is that by the time mod_rewrite sets the environment variable, the auth mod is already done with the request

Comment: You're right, but It would only fail  w/ rewrite in per-directory context.    In vhost context, rewrite runs first.

Comment: Probably feasible, but hard,  to have it work per-dir, but you'd need a non no-op substitution somehow to get processing to restart _and_ a way to not to loop the next go-around.  Kind of ugly even for mod_rewrite!

Answer (score 0):

Don't think you can do what you want here since you can't use mod_rewrite to alter the request (auth module happens before rewrite module) and you can't match against the query string in the request URI. You may need to do something with some redirect trickery, maybe something like:

1. make a symlink of `index.php` called `index2.php` (so that they are the same file)
2. make the `SetEnvIf` call match simply `^/index.php`
3. *Within* the `index.php` script (probably near the very top), have it look for whether or not there's a `myquery` query string, and if not, redirect the request to `/index2.php`
4. When the browser is told to go to `/index2.php` instead, it gets asked for authentication
5. If the browser enters the correct auth, `index.php` gets executed (because of step #1).

Comment: The issue here is that I cannot change any files

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Apache 2.4, SetEnvIf and mod_rewrite workarounds are no longer necessary since the Require directive is able to interpret [expressions](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/expr.html) directly:

Apache 2.4 treats Require directives that are not grouped by  as if they were in a , which behaves as an "or" statement.

Allow access to /callbacks/foo

```
Require expr %{REQUEST_URI} =~ m#^/callbacks/.*#
Require valid-user
```

Allow access to /callbacks/foo?secret_var=42 :

```
Require expr %{QUERY_STRING} = 'secret_var=42'
Require valid-user
```

This example would allow access to /callbacks/foo?secret_var=42 but require a username and password for /callbacks/foo :

```
<RequireAny>
    <RequireAll>
        # I'm using the alternate matching form here so I don't have
        # to escape the /'s in the URL.
        Require expr %{REQUEST_URI} =~ m#^/callbacks/.*#
        Require expr %{QUERY_STRING} = 'secret_var=42'
    </RequireAll>

    Require valid-user
</RequireAny>
```